# Python pathos mulitprocessing "not defined" issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm using the `pathos` for multiprocessing, and I'm trying to understand the following behavior.  The following example works fine:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
import numpy as np


def f(x0, Dt, n_steps):
    x = x0
    for j in range(n_steps):
        x+=-Dt * x
    return x

Dt = 0.1
n_steps = 10
n_runs = 8

x0_vals = np.linspace(-1,1,n_runs)

g = lambda x0: f(x0, Dt, n_steps)

pool = ProcessPool(nodes=4)
results =pool.map(g, x0_vals)

print(results)
```

produces

```
[-0.3486784401, -0.24905602864285714, -0.1494336171857143, -0.049811205728571444, 0.04981120572857141, 0.1494336171857142, 0.24905602864285714, 0.3486784401]
```

Now, if, instead, I had placed the `pool = ProcessPool(nodes=4)` earlier in the code, like

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
import numpy as np


def f(x0, Dt, n_steps):
    x = x0
    for j in range(n_steps):
        x+=-Dt * x
    return x

pool = ProcessPool(nodes=4)

Dt = 0.1
n_steps = 10
n_runs = 8

g = lambda x0: f(x0, Dt, n_steps)

x0_vals = np.linspace(-1,1,n_runs)
results =pool.map(g, x0_vals)
#pool.clear()

print(results)
```

then I get errors like:

```
NameError: name 'Dt' is not defined
```

I presume this is because the variable `Dt` is not defined on the workers in the pool.  Is there a way to control that?  Or should I just stick to only initializing the worker pool at the last possible moment?

Comment: multiprocessing only copies the state that exists before the process spits (Im not familliar with pathos so im not sure what its `ProcessPool` is or how it works specifically, so im just guessing that this is the cause of the behaviour you see)

Comment: Shot in the dark: the solution may be as simple as renaming a few variables.Tricky things can happen when you use the same variable names in global and local namespaces like this, so most IDEs will raise warnings when you do it. In your global namespace rename `Dt`, `n_steps`, and `x0` to something else and see if that helps

Comment: Changing the variables to be `Dt_` and `n_steps_` in `f` made no change.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - so the child process only has access to what was already defined in the parent process?  If that's the case, then I just need to ensure everything that I need is defined before opening the pool?